# Calculating an average using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm getting a *strange* result when trying to create a new column that includes an average. I wonder if someone could explain the result.

**This code exemplifies my problem:**

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(year = c(2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011),
             cases = c(10:14), 
             disease = c("A","B","A","B","C"))

df %>% 
   spread(year, cases, fill = 0) %>% 
   mutate(average = sum(`2010`, `2011`)/2)
```

**I get the following results:**

[image]

Why is my average column full of 30's? What am I not seeing here?

Comment: you have to include `rowwise() %>%` between the two lines or use   `mutate(average = (`2010` + `2011`)/2)` or calculate first then spread `df %>% 
  group_by(disease) %>% 
  mutate(average = sum(cases)/2) %>% 
  spread(year, cases, fill = 0) `

Comment: Thanks very much @Roman - that worked perfectly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you add a `group_by` you will get the result you are expecting. So, I presume that your `mutate` function performs the sum of the full dataset instead of doing it for each condition. (as mentionned by @Roman, `rowwise` should worked too).

```
df %>% 
  spread(year, cases, fill = 0) %>% 
  group_by(disease) %>%
  mutate(average = sum(`2010`, `2011`)/2)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   disease [3]
  disease `2010` `2011` average
  <fct>    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A           10     12      11
2 B           11     13      12
3 C            0     14       7
```

Comment: Thanks very much @dc37