# Is there an R code I could use to average the row values that have the same Date AND Code?

Tags: r

I would like to go from this:
| Date   | Code| Value|
|--------| ----|------|
|2017-S1 | 168 | 20000|
|2017-S1 | 168 | 25000|
|2017-S2 | 168 | 22000|
|2017-S1 | 169 | 20000|
|2017-S2 | 169 | 26000|

To this:
| Date   | Code| Value|
|--------| ----|------|
|2017-S1 | 168 | 22500|
|2017-S2 | 168 | 22000|
|2017-S1 | 169 | 20000|
|2017-S2 | 169 | 26000|

Comment: You can try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052850/calculating-an-average-using-tidyverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `group_by` the variables `Code` and `Date` and then `summarise` `Value` using the `mean`function:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Date, Code) %>%
   summarise(Value = mean(Value))
```